# ls -lu does not give last access time

Tags: linux, files, ls, timestamps, atime

The manpage of `ls` says:

```
   -u     with -lt: sort by, and show, access time; with -l: show access time and sort by name;
          otherwise: sort by access time
```

but that doesn't seem to work:

```
test@debian:~$ date > file
test@debian:~$ date
Sun Jan 17 13:21:12 CET 2016
test@debian:~$ cat file 
Sun Jan 17 13:20:10 CET 2016
test@debian:~$ ls -lu file 
-rw-r--r-- 1 test test 29 Jan 17 13:21 file
test@debian:~$ date
Sun Jan 17 13:22:02 CET 2016
test@debian:~$ cat file 
Sun Jan 17 13:20:10 CET 2016
test@debian:~$ ls -lu file 
-rw-r--r-- 1 test test 29 Jan 17 13:21 file
```

One should expect instead (since the last access time was at 13:22 or later) something like:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 test test 29 Jan 17 13:22 file
```

What is the explanation? Is the file buffered?

Comment: What does `stat file` show for the access time? Same thing?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick: Yes, it gives the same access time as `ls -lu`.

Answer (score 6):

Your filesystem is mounted with `relatime` by default.  Access times will not be updated, if they're already newer than or equal to the modified time of the file.

This is an (POSIX-violating) optimization, to avoid every single file read causing a write to the disk.

Apparent atime updates are not affected by buffering.  (`lazyatime` will buffer atime for up to 24 hours - but the in-memory atime will be updated every time, and that's what `ls` will show.).

Comment: It does not even work if I use the mount option `strictatime`.

Comment: `mount -oremount,strictatime /` makes it (temporarily) work for me.  I don't have /home on a separate partition.  You need to show us your mount details e.g. `grep -w /home /proc/mounts`.  Replace /home with / if necessary.

Comment: "Access times will not be updated, if they're already older or equal to" — should that be "newer or equal to"?

Comment: @Celada ah-heh, fixed.